# javascript vs jQuery form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, validation

Hi I have a simple form validation before I submit the form. 
the validation if working fine with simple javascript function but I try to use the jQuery but its not working with as expected.
Here is the code I am using:

JSP:

```
    <form action="/newManager.do" onsubmit="return validateListPropFields()" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="saveNewPropManagerInfo"/>
    <td>Name<span class="required">*required</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" /></td>
    <input type="image" src="../images/common/submit_property.png" alt="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

Javascript works fine:

```
function validateListPropFields(){
            var name = jQuery("#name").val();
            if( name==""){
                        return false;
            }
            else{
                 return true;
            }
}
```

JQuery doesnot works:

```
function validateListPropFields(){
   jQuery.noConflict();
    (function($) { 
      $(function() {
            var name = jQuery("#name").val();
            if( name==""){
                        return false;
            }
            else{
                 return true;
            }
       });
})(jQuery);
}
```

Here I want to understand what makes the jQuery to not to work as expected?

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict();` will remove `$` reference to jQuery. Why are you using it here?  EDIT: ok, got quite confused by indentation, not your issue here. For your issue, see @Tarmo's answer

Comment: You are using jQuery in both examples.

Comment: I know I am using jQuery in both the places but still I was not able to get the same result that was my question. And Tarmo answered my question correctly. I was trying to understand whats the difference among two functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of jQuery your `validateListPropFields()` function does not return anything. In this function there is an anonymous function which returns true or false but that has no effect on the outer function.

Though I have no Idea why would you want to complicate things so much I made some adjustments to your code so that it would work:

```
function validateListPropFields(){
  jQuery.noConflict();
  return (function($) { 
    return (function() {
        var name = jQuery("#name").val();
        if( name==""){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    });
  })()(jQuery);
}
```

By submiting this code I am not saying that this is a good way to do this. I just wanted to illustrate how to make those inner anonymous functions work for your outer function.

Comment: your right Tarmo this is what I wanted to know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must import the jquery library first

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It works for me

```
function validateListPropFields() {
    if ($("#name").val() == "") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might work for you but this code is not the code what OP posted.

Comment: this works for the asker as well. Also, "works for me" is a close reason, not an answer.